# 503 error IIS7 - no log file

Tags: iis-7.5, 503-error

I have a win2008 R2 VPS from webfusion. I have a couple of asp.net 4.0 websites hosted that were working ok. I tried installing an SSL cert for one of them, made a mess of it and removed the cert. Now when I try to browse to the aspx page I get "HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable". I checked the location where the IIS log file for the site should be but there are no recent entries in the log.

The Server also hosts a Plesk Control Panel php site, this continues to work ok.

Any ideas on possible cause or next steps for diagnosis?

Comment: Do you have other sites defined in IIS?  Can you check if one of them is getting the requests instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check whether the Application Pool serving the web site/web application is Stopped. If it is, start it, browse to the ASP.NET page again.

If it fails again, still with "HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable", open the Event Viewer (`eventvwr`), open the application log, and see if there are any errors indicating worker process or application pool failures.

Comment: Thank you! The app pool had stopped because the password of the custom account it was running under had been changed. Then during the chaos of the cert installation the server was rebooted.